# Batch file to search for content in "%~1"

Tags: batch-file

I'm new to this so please be gentle !

Am running a script that takes a file path from a program and puts it into %1 and this part is working.

Need to search for ~$ in %1 and if found delete the file.

Script for far:

```
set FILE_Path="%~1"  
ECHO "%FILE_PATH%" | FINDSTR "~$"  
IF..... **(not sure what to put in here)**  
DEL "%FILE_PATH%"  
PAUSE
```

any help appreciated

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set "FILE_Path=%~1"
IF NOT DEFINED file_path ECHO no File Path provided&GOTO :eof
ECHO %~1| FINDSTR "~$"
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO DEL %FILE_PATH%
```

Now - a few cautions.

Setting `file_path`  using `set FILE_Path="%~1"` will work, BUT the variable `file_path` (variable names are case-insensitive) to ((the first parameter minus enclosing quotes) enclosed in quotes)

Echoing that version again enclosed in quotes (which doubles-up the quotes) into `FINDSTR` should do `findstr`'s thing - and your object appears to be to find `~$` in the string (but you don't specify this explicitly)

`FINDSTR` will dutifully report any matching string found and set `errorlevel` to 0 if found and 1 if not.

The magic line you are looking for is

```
if not errorlevel 1 ....
```

because

```
if errorlevel 0 ....
```

will ALWAYS trigger - the `if errorlevel n` syntax means `if errorlevel is n OR GREATER THAN n`

It is possible to use

```
if %errorlevel%==0 ...
```

or

```
if %errorlevel% equ 0 ...
```

BUT this syntax doesn't work in a `block` statement like

```
for ... do (something & something else&if %errorlevel%==0 anotherthing)
```

Bit there's a nasty gotcha in this scheme. By default, `findstr` matches on `regular expressions` - so `findstr "~$"` will match `~` at the end of the string, not `~$` anywhere within the string.

Since you don't say which match you want, it's not possible to say whether you actually want `findstr "~$"` (find `~` at end) or `findstr /l "~$"` (find "~$" somewhere) - or perhaps `FIND "~$"` may better suit your purpose (`FIND`, not `FINDSTR`)

Returning to your original, then - what you were doing is echoing the string `""parameter one""` into findstr - which doesn't end with `~` and hence would never be found...

As I've posted, setting `file_path` with quotes surrounding the entire assignment clause ensures that the variable does not get set to (any trailing spaces on the line left by your editor) - which is a right cow to find the first time you encounter it (note that batch is very sensitive to stray spaces - you must omit them in a `SET` before the `=` else they get included in the variable-name and also after the `=` else they get included in the value assigned `SET /A` is a different animal - it tolerates spaces...)

I've also reduced the quote-count to a sensible number - only those required. Batch ALWAYS works on strings. No exceptions. Even `set /a` converts the strings involved into binary, does the mathematics and then converts back to a string when assigning the result.

Comment: sorry I should have said that yes I would like to find ~$

Comment: I'm after findstr /l "~$" (find "~$" somewhere)

I'll try out in the morning and let you know how we go

Comment: Need a bit more time to test this

Answer (score 1):

you can just conditional execution:

```
set FILE_Path="%~1"
ECHO %FILE_PATH% | FIND "~$" && DEL /q /f %FILE_PATH%
PAUSE
```

here's more info: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/condexec.php

Comment: +1, Not sure if the OP wants the `$` to be a literal, or a regular expression end-of-line anchor. If it is to be a literal, then the /L option should be added to the FINDSTR command to force interpretation as a literal string.